# Merge an array which has 2 sorted parts in place

Tags: algorithm, sorting, merge

Given an array, which has 2 parts, each part is sorted (e.g. 2 4 6 8 1 3 5), write a function to make whole array sorted.

Requirements:

1. in place, which means O(1) space complexity.
2. as quick as possible.

It is easy to write a O(n<sup>2</sup>) or O(n logn) (use binary search to find insert location) solution, I am wondering if it is possible to get an O(n) solution?

Comment: In-place merge exists, but it is somewhat surprisingly rather tricky to understand ([example](http://www.drdobbs.com/parallel/parallel-in-place-merge/240008783)).

Comment: Do you have any additional info about the input? Are the two parts (roughly) the same size? Is the range of values in both parts (roughly) the same?

Comment: @m69 No additional information, you cannot assume anything. Just use the info given in question.

Comment: This is an extremely well-studied algorithm called in-place merge, though usually the sublists differ in length by at most one, making this version a bit harder. See for example https://xinok.wordpress.com/2014/08/17/in-place-merge-sort-demystified-2/

Comment: Or a discussion of linear time algorithms: http://www.akira.ruc.dk/~keld/teaching/algoritmedesign_f04/Artikler/04/Huang88.pdf

Comment: Ah sry , didn't notice O(1) space complexity:)

Comment: @Gene Thanks, I had never imaged that the solution is so complicate, I doubt it is a proper question for a coding interview - obviously for someone who never reads that paper before, he cannot get right solution within 45 minutes.

Answer (score 3):

Simple in-place merge algorithms usually make swapped items bubble up to their correct position in the second zone. As an improvement on this, I create an ordered "swap zone" inbetween the two zones, where the position of a newly swapped item is always at the end, so it can be moved into place more efficiently.

[image: in-place merge with swap zone]

We start off with two sorted zones. *(fig. 1)* The items in zone 1 are compared one-by-one, from left to right, with the first item in zone 2, and swapped if necessary. As soon as an item in zone 1 is swapped, it creates a swap zone between zone 1 and 2. *(fig. 2)* From then on, items in zone 1 are compared with both the first item in zone 2, and with the first item in the swap zone. This creates two situations:

- A swap between zone 1 and 2: in this case, the swapped item becomes the last item of the swap zone; it is the largest item in the swap zone, and the swap zone remains correctly sorted. *(fig. 2-3)*
- A swap between zone 1 and the swap zone: in this case, the swapped item becomes the first item in the swap zone; however, it is the largest in the swap zone, so it has to be moved to the end of the swap zone. *(fig. 3-5)*

When zone 1 is completely merged, the swap zone then becomes the new zone 1, and the algorithm starts again with the remainder of the array. *(fig. 6)*

```js
function mergeInPlace(array) {
    var zone2 = 0, swapzone = 0;
    // FIND START OF ZONE 2
    while (array[zone2] <= array[++zone2]);
    // ITERATE OVER ALL ITEMS IN ZONE 1
    for (var zone1 = 0; zone1 < zone2; zone1++) {
        // WHEN ZONE 1 IS SORTED, TREAT SWAP ZONE AS NEW ZONE 1
        if (zone1 == swapzone) swapzone = zone2;
        // CHECK WHETHER SWAP ZONE OR ZONE 2 HAS SMALLEST FIRST ITEM
        if (array[zone2] <= array[swapzone]) {
            // COMPARE AND SWAP WITH FIRST ITEM OF ZONE 2
            if (array[zone1] > array[zone2]) {
                var temp = array[zone1];
                array[zone1] = array[zone2];
                array[zone2++] = temp;
            }
        }
        // COMPARE AND SWAP WITH FIRST ITEM OF SWAP ZONE
        else if (array[zone1] > array[swapzone]) {
            var temp = array[zone1];
            array[zone1] = array[swapzone];
            // MOVE SWAPPED ITEM TO END OF SWAP ZONE
            for (var i = swapzone; i < zone2 - 1; i++) {
                array[i] = array[i + 1];
            }
            array[zone2 - 1] = temp;
        }
    }
}

var a = [2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47,51,1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55];
mergeInPlace(a);
document.write(a);
```